# createSelector returns a function and not the selected state

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm try to use `createSelector` from `@redux/toolkit` to memoize a calcullation for the some items in the state but I'm not getting any data -not even undefined or empty array- as an output.

**Inside my component**

// import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

```
  const stateInstitutions = (state) => state.institutions.items;
  const ins = useSelector(stateInstitutions);
  const institutionsOptions = createSelector(
    stateInstitutions,
    // this is what I want to do
    // (institutions) => institutions.map(({ name }) => ({ label: name, value: name })), 
    (institutions) => institutions, // just for testing
  );
  console.log(ins, institutionsOptions);
```

The log output is

```
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] ƒ memoized() {
    var value = cache.get(arguments);

    if (value === NOT_FOUND) {
      // @ts-ignore
      value = func.apply(null, arguments);

      if (resultEqualityCheck) {
        var entries…
```

As you can see I'm pointing to the right selector since I get the data from `useSelector` but not with `createSelector`.

Some silly error I must be doing but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `createSelector` returns a selector. You still need to pass the selector your state.

e.g.

```js
const stateInstitutions = (state) => state.institutions.items;
const ins = useSelector(stateInstitutions);
const institutionOptionSelector = createSelector(
    stateInstitutions,
    (institutions) => institutions.map(({ name }) => ({ label: name, value: name })), 
  );
const instOptions = useSelector(institutionOptionSelector);
console.log(ins, institutionsOptions);
```

Comment: Is this the regular behaviour of createSelector? Can't believe I haven't seen it in the docs. Thank you!